# How to add canActivate: [AuthGuard], in loadChildren in the same route

Tags: nativescript, angular2-routing, nativescript-angular

I have app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "/fp", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "home", loadChildren: "~/app/home/home.module#HomeModule" },
    { path: "login", loadChildren: "~/app/accounts/login/login.module#LoginModule" },
    { path: "register", loadChildren: "~/app/accounts/registers/registers.module#RegistersModule" },
 { path: "fp", loadChildren: "~/app/accounts/first_page/first_page.module#FirstPageModule" },
];
export const routing = NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules});
```

In Home Component I have home-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: HomeComponent }
];
```

In LoginComponent I have login-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: LoginComponent }
];
```

In RegisterComponent I have resgister-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: RegistersComponent }
];
```

In RegisterComponent I have first_page-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: FirstPageComponent }
];
```

I create a authguard like this:

```
canActivate(): boolean {
        if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            console.log('true')
             return true;
      }
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        console.log('false')
         return false;
     }
```

My question is, how to use AuthGuard in my routing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and add the guard in the app routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/fp', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', loadChildren: '~/app/home/home.module#HomeModule' },
    {
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: '~/app/accounts/login/login.module#LoginModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'register',
        loadChildren:
            '~/app/accounts/registers/registers.module#RegistersModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'fp',
        loadChildren:
            '~/app/accounts/first_page/first_page.module#FirstPageModule',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    }
];
```

... assuming you only want to protect the `fp` path.